# Difference between imported schema and local schema with Pydantic

Tags: python, testing, import, pydantic

I ran into an interesting issue I am not sure how to solve.

I have a library in which I create a pydantic schema to validate on. Something like:

```
class LibSchema(pydantic.BaseModel):
   attr: str
```

I import the schema from python library and want to do this:

```
class CustomSchema(LibSchema):
   def some_custom_functionality:
      pass
```

When I wanted to validate according to `CustomSchema` I ran into validation errors from pydantic. I wanted to fix them so I got into debugging this. For debugging purposes I copied the `LibSchema` into my current application and to my surprise. When I inherit from it there it works without issues. So now I have no idea why it would not be working just because it is imported.
Does anyone have an idea here?